# Subdomain redirects to root domain with Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

It's possible I don't know how to ask the right question, but I can't seem to find an answer to what's going on here anywhere. I have a Wordpress installation at example123.com, and want to set up a node application to run at licensing.example123.com. The problem I'm running into is when I put in licensing.example123.com, I keep getting forwarded to the wordpress site. I can't figure out a way to stop it. I don't see any special rules in .htaccess.. Does anybody have any ideas? Further details can be furnished upon request. TIA!

Comment: Did you check your WordPress site's home URL setting?

Comment: And/Or your web server config?

Comment: This will be a server configuration challenege and not something strictly related to WordPress. If your subdomain is configured to load from the same folder as WP, WordPress will kick in and redirect.

Comment: @Samy, the home URL is set to https://example123.com. What web server config are you referring to?

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: @NathanDawson I tried mapping the subdomain to a different folder. It still doesn't seem to be working properly

Comment: @Samy it's a cPanel site. It looks like Apache 2.4.46

Comment: Check Your DocumentToot and ServerAlias parameters in your webserver config. This thread could be helpful: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/documentroot-and-httpd-conf.359282/#post1450471